# How can I replicate key presses with click handlers?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a game I made with HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript. I have images of joystick arrows. I would like users to be able to click my joystick arrows and have it work as if the arrows on the keyboard were pressed. I wrote the code like this but it doesn't work:

```
var $rt_arrow = $('.rt_arrow') 

$rt_arrow.on('click' , function (e) {
e.keyCode == 39 
}
```

How do I make keyCode 39 fire when the image of the right arrow is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would be a clearer approach to write a callback function and assign it to the keyboard right arrow and to the right arrow.

```
function goRight() { console.log('I go right');}

$('.rt_arrow').on('click', goRight);
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if ( e.key === 'ArrowRight' ) {
        goRight();
    }
});
```